# Why do vertices sometimes not dissapear when I try to delete them?

Tags: mesh

I'm working on a simple mesh and I'm trying to delete a vertex.

I've selected in Edit & Wiremesh mode by right-clicking. then hitting X - V which is Delete -> Vertices.

When I select groups sometimes all but one vertex is deleted.

The vertex isn't covered by any other mesh or object in the scene; Hidden or visible.

Does anyone know why repeatedly attempting to delete a vertex would fail? I can select and attempt to delete it and then afterward it's still visually there in the mesh BUT I can no longer select it.

Comment: Can you share screenshots of this issue?